# How to "shrink" repetitive virtually identical javascript/jQuery lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm quite new in programming with javascript/jQuery and managed to have the following work but I'm sure there is a way to "shrink" it in a few lines of code. I've tried with *each.* but didn't manage to work.

What this piece of code does is:
1) You have some divs with "labels" in them.
2) You save a custom title with localStorage through the inputs
3) The titles are updated

Here is [jsFiddle for this](https://jsfiddle.net/b56669bd/) too

Code:

```
<div id="theater-1" class="theater">theater 1</div>
<div id="theater-2" class="theater">theater 2</div>
<div id="theater-3" class="theater">theater 3</div>
<div id="theater-4" class="theater">theater 4</div>
<div id="theater-5" class="theater">theater 5</div>



1
<input type="text" id="theater_name_1" class="input-for-theater-title">
<button id="save-title-1">Save</button>
<br> 2
<input type="text" id="theater_name_2" class="input-for-theater-title">
<button id="save-title-2">Save</button>
<br> 3
<input type="text" id="theater_name_3" class="input-for-theater-title">
<button id="save-title-3">Save</button>
<br> 4
<input type="text" id="theater_name_4" class="input-for-theater-title">
<button id="save-title-4">Save</button>
<br> 5
<input type="text" id="theater_name_5" class="input-for-theater-title">
<button id="save-title-5">Save</button>


<button id="clear">Clear</button>

<script>
    var theater_1_saved_name = localStorage.getItem("theater_1_name");
    var theater_2_saved_name = localStorage.getItem("theater_2_name");
    var theater_3_saved_name = localStorage.getItem("theater_3_name");
    var theater_4_saved_name = localStorage.getItem("theater_4_name");
    var theater_5_saved_name = localStorage.getItem("theater_5_name");

    if (theater_1_saved_name !== null) {
        document.getElementById("theater-1").innerHTML = theater_1_saved_name;
        document.getElementById("theater_name_1").value = theater_1_saved_name;

    };
    if (theater_2_saved_name !== null) {
        document.getElementById("theater-2").innerHTML = theater_2_saved_name;
        document.getElementById("theater_name_2").value = theater_2_saved_name;
    };
    if (theater_3_saved_name !== null) {
        document.getElementById("theater-3").innerHTML = theater_3_saved_name;
        document.getElementById("theater_name_3").value = theater_3_saved_name;
    };
    if (theater_4_saved_name !== null) {
        document.getElementById("theater-4").innerHTML = theater_4_saved_name;
        document.getElementById("theater_name_4").value = theater_4_saved_name;
    };
    if (theater_5_saved_name !== null) {
        document.getElementById("theater-5").innerHTML = theater_5_saved_name;
        document.getElementById("theater_name_5").value = theater_5_saved_name;
    };


    $("#save-title-1").click(function () {
        var title_of_1 = $('#theater_name_1').val();
        localStorage.setItem("theater_1_name", title_of_1);
        $("#theater-1").text(title_of_1);
    });
    $("#save-title-2").click(function () {
        var title_of_2 = $('#theater_name_2').val();
        localStorage.setItem("theater_2_name", title_of_2);
        $("#theater-2").text(title_of_2);
    });
    $("#save-title-3").click(function () {
        var title_of_3 = $('#theater_name_3').val();
        localStorage.setItem("theater_3_name", title_of_3);
        $("#theater-3").text(title_of_3);
    });
    $("#save-title-4").click(function () {
        var title_of_4 = $('#theater_name_4').val();
        localStorage.setItem("theater_4_name", title_of_4);
        $("#theater-4").text(title_of_4);
    });

    $("#save-title-5").click(function () {
        var title_of_5 = $('#theater_name_5').val();
        localStorage.setItem("theater_5_name", title_of_5);
        $("#theater-5").text(title_of_5);
    });
    $("#clear").click(function () {
        localStorage.clear();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "I've tried with each. but didn't manage to work." - can you show what you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops and string concatenation, look for `n` in the below for the changes:

```
var n;
for (n = 1; n <= 5; ++n) {
    var theater_saved_name = localStorage.getItem("theater_" + n + "_name");
    if (theater_saved_name !== null) {
        document.getElementById("theater-" + n).innerHTML = theater_saved_name;
        document.getElementById("theater_name_" + n).value = theater_saved_name;
    }
    $("#save-title-" + n).click(function () {
        var title = $('#theater_name_' + n).val();
        localStorage.setItem("theater_" + n + "_name", title);
        $("#theater-" + n).text(title);
    });
}
```

That changes *only* your JavaScript, not your HTML or the way you store things in local storage. You could change those as well, for instance using a common class for the elements and getting collections of the relevant elements you could index into, but the above is the JavaScript-only change.

Here's an example that changes your HTML (you already mostly had common classes) and local storage; the key is the `index` argument/variable:

[On jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b56669bd/2/) (Stack Snippets don't support local storage, grrr)

HTML:

```
<div class="theater">theater 1</div>
<div class="theater">theater 2</div>
<div class="theater">theater 3</div>
<div class="theater">theater 4</div>
<div class="theater">theater 5</div>

1
<input type="text" class="input-for-theater-title">
<button class="save-title">Save</button>
<br>2
<input type="text" class="input-for-theater-title">
<button class="save-title">Save</button>
<br>3
<input type="text" class="input-for-theater-title">
<button class="save-title">Save</button>
<br>4
<input type="text" class="input-for-theater-title">
<button class="save-title">Save</button>
<br>5
<input type="text" class="input-for-theater-title">
<button class="save-title">Save</button>

<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var theaters = $(".theater");
var inputs = $(".input-for-theater-title");
var buttons = $(".save-title");
theaters.each(function(index) {
    var name = localStorage.getItem("theater_" + index + "_name") || "";
    $(this).html(name);
    inputs.eq(index).val(name);
});
$(document.body).on("click", ".save-title", function() {
    var index = buttons.index(this);
    var title = inputs.eq(index).val();
    localStorage.setItem("theater_" + index + "_name", title);
    theaters.eq(index).text(title);
});
```

Comment: 58 lines of code in just 14 lines? That's optimisation! Thank you very much T.J. My only concern is that with the optimised code, we lost the part where if the value is not stored it just shows the initial "Theater 1"

Comment: @Jim: Ah, sorry, just have been an editing error. Just add back the `if`, e.g.: `if (name) { $(this).html(name); inputs.eq(index).val(name); }`

Comment: Fantastic! I added this to the jsFiddle just in case anyone else needs to see it complete: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/b56669bd/3/)